# add to home screen to an image

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I have a download button in my PHP page. And after click on that button, an image is downloads. But my boss need downloaded image like an app icon. If any one download the image, then an icon should be save and if click on that icon then downloaded images should be show.

I tried it by **"Add to home screen"**. And it is on page reload.

index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template One</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon512.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer template1">
        hello
    </div>
 </body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
console.log("Will the service worker register?");
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
  .then(function(reg){
    console.log("Yes, it did.");
 }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
});
}
 </script>
</html>
```

service-worker.js is:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
```

manifest.json is:

```
{
"short_name": "Test App",
"name": "Web Test App",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "icon192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
},
{
  "src": "icon512.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "512x512"
}
],
"start_url": "http://localhost/add_to_home_screen3/",
"background_color": "#3367D6",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

It is not showing any add to homescreen button.

In console:

```
Will the service worker register?
(index):24 Yes, it did.
```

And I tested my code in desktop chrome localhost.

**I have some queries:**

1- Why it is not working. Is any problem in code from my side or it will be run only mobile browser?

2- Can I give my image name url in **start_url in manifest.json**.

3- Is above approach is correct to get my output or I can get my output by other way?

Comment: Please suggest any other way to do my output. If it is not correct way.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: No, I am running in my localhost.

Comment: In order to "Install" a PWA, it needs to be validated by the browser. If it is not, all you are adding to your home screen is a shortcut to a website.

Comment: I need to save my downloaded image as icon in mobile. And If click on that icon, downloaded image should be show. Can it is possible from my above try?